# Netbeans Object Explorer equivalent of Visual Studio Object Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2008, netbeans, explorer

Is there a Netbeans Object Explorer equivalent of the Visual Studio Object Explorer?  If not is there one in any of the Eclipse releases (i.e. Helios)?

Just a useful tool that I use a lot in Visual Studio and miss in Netbeans.  I have to use the intellisense to look for classes from the code editor.

**Screenshot of VS2008 Object Explorer:**

[image]

Thanks

Andez

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is:

- **Navigator Window** - shows all members, methods etc. of your class
- **Javadoc Window** - shows the javadoc (there's one for showing the sourcecode as well, also shows up eg. C/C++ documentation)
- Typing eg. `System.` will show you all methods / members of this class, including full javadoc of it
- **Classes Window** - Class-browser (C/C++)
- `ctrl + left` mouse will open the full sourcecode of the file, additional it will be displayed at the Navigation Window (see above)
- Open `Libraries` in the tree view shows you all libraries of you project, you now can browse through all your packages, classes, interfaces, methods, fields, ... as you much as you need

Here's a goog screenshot from the internet: http://pliki.onet.pl/zdjecia/pliki/n/netbeans-cpp.jpg (showing C/C++)

Comment: Yes, the C++ classes window is pretty much what I want.  Unfortunately I am using Java - I guess I should have mentioned that in the post - sorry :-( - still +1 though for that info, although I constantly use the Javadoc and the Navigator.

Comment: But isn't the Libraries part of the probject explorer + the navigator + javadoc very similar to this? I mean, in the explorer you see packages / Object, Navigator shows methods / fields and javadoc ...  well shows the doc :-) Btw. another approach is using javadoc only, since it already contains most (if not all) informations. You can open javadoc for a libraries with righclick on --> show javadoc